# Mouse scroll events in the terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, x11, macos, xterm

I am trying to catch mouse scroll events in the terminal for my text editor. I have a couple questions.

Firstly, how can [alternate scroll mode](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:alternateScroll) be enabled? Am I interpreting it correctly that when the `alternate buffer` is specified via `\x1b[?1049h` then scrolls are sent as `<key-up>` and `<key-down>`?

Specifically, I'm unable to understand this:

> However if Alternate Scroll mode is set, then cursor up/down controls
> are sent when the terminal is displaying the Alternate Screen Buffer.
> The initial state of Alternate Scroll mode is set using the
> alternateScroll resource.

I am able to catch the scroll actions in the form `\x1b[MCbCxCy` in the below program, but I am not aware of an Alternate Scroll mode.

My second question is that for the [above](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking) where are Cx and Cy coming from? It seems completely non-deterministic in my terminal. Here is a sample program you can copy paste to see this:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ENABLE_ALT_SCREEN "\x1b[?1049h"
#define DISABLE_ALT_SCREEN "\x1b[?1049l"
#define ENABLE_ALT_SCREEN_SZ 8
#define DISABLE_ALT_SCREEN_SZ ENABLE_ALT_SCREEN_SZ

#define ENABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING "\x1b[?1000h"
#define DISABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING "\x1b[?1000l"
#define ENABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING_SZ 8
#define DISABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING_SZ ENABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING_SZ

struct termios orig_termios;

void
disable_raw_mode (void)
{
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &orig_termios);
  write(STDIN_FILENO, DISABLE_ALT_SCREEN,DISABLE_ALT_SCREEN_SZ);
  write(STDIN_FILENO, DISABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING, DISABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING_SZ);  
}

void
enable_raw_mode (void)
{
  write(STDIN_FILENO, ENABLE_ALT_SCREEN,ENABLE_ALT_SCREEN_SZ);
  write(STDIN_FILENO, ENABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING, ENABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING_SZ);  
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &orig_termios);
  atexit(disable_raw_mode);

  struct termios raw = orig_termios;
  raw.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | INPCK | PARMRK | INLCR | IGNCR | ISTRIP | ICRNL | IXON);
  //  raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
  raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
  raw.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
  raw.c_cflag |= (CS8);


  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}

int
main (void)
{
  enable_raw_mode();
  
  char c;
  while ( read(STDIN_FILENO,  &c, 1) == 1 && c != 'q')
    {
      if (iscntrl(c))
        printf("%d\n", c);
      else
        printf("%d ('%c')\n", c, c);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

My terminal is `xterm-256color`.

Comment: Cx and Cy are single raw bytes representing the coordinates. Please do not use the legacy "1000" mouse mode without extensions in newly written apps, as sending raw bytes breaks after row or column 223, in fact, breaks the UTF-8-validness of the stream (potentially causing subtle problems here and there) after 95 rows or columns. Please enable the "1006" extension as well (as in `"\x1b[?1006h"`) in addition to enabling the "1000" mouse reporting mode, this way you'll receive the coordinates as decimal numbers.

Comment: The weirdness comes from the randomness of the raw bytes @egmont. You can see the program prints them in decimal form. Is there a preferred mouse mode to "1000" that can capture scroll events for my application?

Comment: Again: the "randomness" are the x and y coordinates of the scroll event.

Comment: Alternate scroll mode only matters if your application does _not_ enable mouse support. If you wish to explicitly handle mouse events (as you do) then it's irrelevant for you.

Comment: First make your app work in 1000 mode. Then, if anyone will ever use your app in a terminal wider than 223 chars then implement 1000+1006 mode, too. Enable both 1000 and 1006, however, be prepared to parse both input formats (as the terminal does not necessarily support the 1006 extension). Luckily the two formats do not clash, you can always tell which format arrived. If the terminal supports the 1006 extension (most do) then you'll be able to handle arbitrarily large coordinates; if it doesn't then you're back to the limited 1000 behavior.

Comment: Another approach, if you are not interested in any other mouse events than scrolling, is to _not_ enable mouse support, however, switch to the alternate screen and enable alternate scroll mode. In this case, if the terminal supports it, it will send you up and down keystrokes (exactly as if the user pressed those keys).

Comment: @egmont 1049 (alternate buffer) + 1007 (alternate scroll) doesn't capture scroll events for me. I tested this by replacing the "1000" in the program attached with a "1007". As for the randomness, from the same position (x-y coordinates) it occasionally gives different bytes/values. This is why I said it is random. In "1000" mode I'm able to capture mouse scroll events by looking specially for their Cb values, and disgarding Cx and Cy. I'm still curious if 1006 mode would be needed for larger terminals in this use case. I'm only curious in 1. has the user scrolled? 2. which direction?

Comment: 1049 + 1007 is supposed to send up/down keypresses _instead_ of mouse scroll events. This is one possible path for you to consider. Alternatively, with real mouse support (1000) the alternate screen 1049 and the alternate scroll 1007 modes are irrelevant. If you occasionally get different bytes than the ones corresponding to your mouse position then your terminal emulator is buggy. Which terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: For the x and y coordinates, it might be somewhat odd at first glimpse that scroll events include these values, but if you consider fullscreen apps with multiple "widgets" then it suddenly all makes sense. If you don't enable the 1006 extension and the coordinate exceeds 223 then the behavior is undefined, e.g. some terminal emulators might omit the entire sequence, you can't know what will happen. So even if you don't care about the coordinates, I highly recommend to enable this extension.

Comment: @egmont I was commenting that 1049 + 1007 did not send the up/down keypresses. You can simply test it with the code I provided. I am not sure if this is a bug with my terminal. I use `xterm-256color`, it is the default `Terminal.app` on MacOS. As for the extension, doesn't that make the escape sequences variable-width, so harder to parse? That is my hesitation. Thank you for the information. Can I ask where you are getting it? You seem to know a lot about this stuff and I have not been able to extract all this information from any of the sources I've seen.

Comment: The setting of `TERM` doesn't matter, what matters is that you're using `Terminal.app`. Apparently this doesn't support alternate scroll mode, so you'll have to live without it. One could argue that it's not a real emulation feature anyway, but rather a quirk provided by terminals for the convenience of users of apps that don't support mouse. So I have to somewhat correct myself. If you want to handle events, relying on this mode is probably not a great idea. You should rather go for proper mouse support (1000 or 1002 or 1003 [for scrolling 1000 is enough], plus the 1006 extension).

Comment: Variable width is a tiny bit harder to parse, but c'mon, reading bytes in a loop until you get enough semicolons and the trailing character isn't that hard, is it? :)

Comment: Where do I get all these? I used to be a co-developer of a popular terminal emulator for years, kept an eye on all these kinds of things, I pushed for a solution to the 95/223 column limit, was close to the fire when the 1006 mode (and two predecessors that suffered from notable problems) were invented, and implemented 1006 support in a few apps. Unfortunately I don't think there's a documentation or wiki out there that summarizes the knowledge and experience that people in your shoes really should have access to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You definitely seem like you'd be able to fulfill that niche @egmont. Do you know if 1000 + 1006 is what vim or nano uses for this? I notice they are able to do it nicely, but I've scoured the source code and haven't been able to find it. My editor flickers heavily with my support for scrolling. I'm also still a bit confused about the 1000 + 1006 necessity, specifically the Cx Cy characters. I'm not sure what to be expecting for Cx Cy since my `Terminal.app` seems to send them randomly, and you keep mentioning 95/223 column limits, whereas a byte can hold 256 distinct values.

Comment: To give you an example, 1000 + 1006, in the simple program I gave that doesn't move the cursor (meaning it is at the leftmost edge of the terminal), gives values like -> 17;21, 41;21, 22;21, from the bottom-left corner of the terminal @egmont

Comment: It seems like this is a real problem, even in vim. I just tried in `Terminal.app` with `M-<mouse click>` to reposition the cursor and it goes randomly around the screen.

Comment: Also, sorry for the continued questions, but is 1000 + 1006 mode important if it is just an ASCII text-editor? I'm not planning to support UTF-8 as of right now.

Comment: I don't know what vim or nano do, you should check their source. I cannot comment on the randomness, if the terminal sends random values then mouse support shouldn't work in any of the apps. I don't have access to `Terminal.app`. Try with other terminals, such as `iTerm2`, see if the numbers are random there. I've tried with `gnome-terminal`, clicking on the same position produces the same numbers, as expected.

Comment: The Cx and Cy raw byte values are 32 more than the coordinate, so at column 224 you'd get an overflow, but already at a value of 96 you'd get invalid UTF-8, you'll face serious problems if you have a charset converting layer such as `luit`. Also, the 223 column limit is reasonably very easy to hit. Just go with the 1006 extension if you want no trouble.

Comment: I see, and at that point, there is no defined behavior for the bytes, but rather the behavior becomes undefined and the terminal can choose not to send any escape sequences? I doubt it would send bad escape sequences -> but I can see Cx Cy becoming garbage or instead it sending none at all.

Answer (score 0):

The quote is from the ***xterm*** manpage, which refers to [private mode 1007](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-h:Ps-=-1-0-0-7.1F7F):

> *Ps* = **`1 0 0 7`**  ⇒  Enable Alternate Scroll Mode, xterm.
> This corresponds to the [**`alternateScroll`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:alternateScroll) resource.

For example

```
printf '\033[?1007h'
```

Other terminals may/may not support the control sequence (check their documentation).

Comment: I am not noticing any difference from this.

Comment: With 1049 + 1007, it does not work as documented.